# What exactly do these lines mean?

Tags: python, tkinter

after you import everything from Tkinter, you have to create a basic, blank window, and that's what this code is for, but what does each line mean?

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Window(Frame):
```

The above code creates a new class. This new class inherits from the `Frame` class, so it can be used anywhere a normal `Frame` can be used.

```
 def __init__(self, master=None):
```

This is the beginning of the initializer for the new class. The initializer is similar in many ways to what other languages call a *constructor*, though it's not technically a constructor. A normal `Frame` can take many arguments, but this subclass takes two. `self` is a required argument for any python class, and is passed in automatically when you call a method on an object. `master` represents the parent, which is required for all Tkinter widgets except for the root window.

Oddly, the default for `master` is `None`. That's very misleading since the parent widget cannot be `None`. If you set it to `None` it will automatically be set to the root window. When creating a new instance of this `Window` class you should always pass in a reference to the parent window.

```
Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

The above completes the process of inheriting from the `Frame` class, by calling the initializer of the superclass. This is what actually creates the widget which you see on the screen. Without this step, no widget will be created.

```
self.master = master
```

The above statement is simply saving the `master` parameter as a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

#### Line by line.

main.py

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None): # initialization: default for master is None
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # Call the parent (Frame) init method
        self.master = master # set the attribute master to self ('gui') 
gui = Window(master=something) # creates object
```

`master` is a parameter when you create your object.